Changing bounds when integrating
I have the function $p(x,y) = 24x$ for $0<x$, $x+y<1$, $x<y$.
I want to find the marginal density of Y, which means I have to integrate over $x$.
My TA told me I have to split the area I want to integrate in two parts, y∈(0,$\frac{1}{2}$) where the upper bound is equal y, and from y ∈ ($\frac{1}{2}$,1) where the upper bound is equal $1-y$. But why can't I just use the upper bound y over the entire area?

$x<y$ and $x<1-y$. One of these automatically implies the other dependng on whether $y <\frac  1 2$ or $y >\frac   12$.

How do I know which one is for y < 1/2 and for y >1/2? I have sketched the area.

For $y <\frac   12$ , $x$ ranges from $0$ to $y$  and for $y >\frac   12$ , $x$ ranges from $0$ to $1-y$.
